# Play music from streaming URL in windows phone app

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to play music from an [url](http://elektro.hostingenlinea.net:8000/airtime_64). I already try with a lot of tools from the toolbox incluiding MediaElement but It doesn't work. So I want to try with webView but not work neither.
Please see 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKt0e.png)

Thanks!

```
   public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
         this.myweb.Navigate(new Uri("http://elektronaradio.com/",UriKind.Absolute));
    }
```

Comment: Please provide your code and detailed description of what exactly is not working.

Comment: ok! done. Web open but nothing sound!

Answer (score 0):

Try [Phonesm](http://phonesm.codeplex.com/). It is library  for implementing internet audio streaming.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play from a remote URL refer this example  [playing Audio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and in the code part remember to include the URL

```
private static List<AudioTrack> _playList = new List<AudioTrack>
    {
        // A remote URI
        new AudioTrack(new Uri("http://traffic.libsyn.com/wpradio/WPRadio_29.mp3", UriKind.Absolute), 
                        "Episode 29", 
                        "Windows Phone Radio", 
                        "Windows Phone Radio Podcast", 
                        null)
    };
```